# Is there a way to find the area between two curves without having to graph them?

Tags: calculus

More specifically, if you are given two functions and you are asked to find the area between the two curves is there a way to do it without having to graph them. So far in calculus class we are taught to graph them to see which one is the upper function and which one is the lower function. For example,

If you are given the following two functions is there a way to find which one is the upper function and lower function without having to graph them?

$x=y-\frac{y^2}{4}$  and $x=\frac{y}{4}$

Comment: All graphing is allowing you to do is visually interpret the intersections of the curves and region of integration. You can of course do this without graphing. Just check where they intersect $4y - y^2 = y \implies y(y-3)=0 \implies y=0, y=3$. As to which one is "upper" or "lower", what do you think?

Comment: Graphing is an aid to help you with you to develop your intuition.  You could disregard which is the upper and which is the lower, and take the absolute value of the final result.  But keeping track of which is which helps with the error checking.  But there are other analytical techniques to see which is upper and lower such as checking an arbitrary point in the middle, or looking at the slopes at the endpoints.

Comment: One way is to compute $\int_{a}^{b}|f(x) - g(x)| \, dx$, although one could legitimately argue that this is sweeping the problem you're asking about under the rug.

Comment: Let me rephrase your question: are blind mathematicians able to determine the area between two curves? The question, when phrased that way, answers itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not, for polynomials at least, any need to even see which is on top on the various intervals determined.

Example:$$f(x)=2x^3-6x^2+13x, \\ g(x)=x^3+x^2+x.$$
Begin by factoring the difference: $f(x)-g(x)=x(x-3)(x-4).$ [really not so easy for arbitrary polynomials, but likely works if doing a typical calc exercise.]

We see the zeros of the difference are $0,\ 3,\ 4.$ Since dealing with an area *between* graphs, the regions before $0$ and after $4$ are not considered (would contribute infinite areas). In the usual method one would see which is on top on each of the intervals $[0,3]$ and $[3,4]$ etc. But since area over each is the integral of the absolute value of $f-g$, which over each is either $f-g$ or $g-f$ [since the crossing point at $3$ was removed], we can complete the process of getting the total area as follows.

Step (1) Get (an) antiderivative $F(x)$ of the difference. Here $F(x)=(1/4)x^4-(7/3)x^3+6x^2.$

Step (2) evaluate $F(x)$ at each intersection point. Here $F(0)=0,\ F(3)=45/4,\ F(4)=32/3.$

Step (3) Add the *absolute values* of the successive differences. $(45/4-0)+(45/4-32/3)=45/4+7/12=71/6.$

So the area is $71/6,$ and we didn't need to know which function is on top during the intervals between intersections. I think this method also works for other reasonable functions defined on the reals, provided we can get effectively a list of values where the functions are equal, *and* we can successfully get a closed form antiderivative, *and* we are not interested in evaluationg improper integrals (which might converge in some cases).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to integrate with respect to $y$. If you want to integrate with repect to $x$, leave me a comment. $:)$

First equal the two equations: $$y-\frac{y^2}{4} = \frac{y}{4}$$
Solving this we get $$y = 0 \text{ or } y = 3$$ (Assuming I'm not making a stupid mistake.)

Now we calculate (evaluate) both functions for three values of $x$, one with $y < 0$, one with $0 < y < 3$ and the last one for $y > 3$. I will use $y = -1$, $y = 1$ and $y = 4$.

For $y = -1$:

$x = y-\frac{y^2}{4} = -1 - \frac{(-1)^2}{4} = -\frac{5}{4}$ and $\frac{y}{4} = \frac{-1}{4} = -\frac{1}{4}$. Since $-\frac{5}{4} < - \frac{1}{4}$, the second function ($x = \frac{y}{4}$) is the upper one for $y < 0$.

For $y = 1$:

$x = y-\frac{y^2}{4} = 1 - \frac{1^2}{4} = \frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{y}{4} = \frac{1}{4} $. Since $-\frac{3}{4} > - \frac{1}{4}$, the first function ($y-\frac{y^2}{4}$) is the upper one for $0 < y < 3$.

For $y = 4$:

$x = y-\frac{y^2}{4} = 4 - \frac{4^2}{4} = 4 - 4 = 0$ and $\frac{4}{4} = 1 $. Since $0 < 1$, the second function ($x = \frac{y}{4}$) is the upper one for $y > 3$.

I hope I'm not making some stupid mistake. $:)$
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Graphing is a convenient visible paper stuff way to see what you are dealing with. Otherwise you may miss out essential details. Or need to labor mentally extra needlessly.

Interchange axes to get the inverse functions

$$ y = x -x^2/4, \quad y =x/4 $$

both of which pass through origin, find other cutting point between straight line and parabola.Area will remain same when you integrate w.r.t. $x$ here.